# Angular - load assets when bundling

Tags: angular

First of all, I would like to appologize if this question has already been answered. I've tried searching both here and on google, but haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for. This might be because I don't know the correct terminology, so I hope you will bear with me.

I'm currently working on an Angular project, that has multiple images that are used for buttons as icons. These images, are stored in assets, in a folder called img (assets/img)

However, when these buttons are displayed, the images are not loaded instantly, but rather have a request to /assets/img/"name of image" in the network tab. This causes the images to be loaded after a very minor delay. This wouldn't be the biggest of issues, but I believe this is the cause of another issue we're facing.

In our application, we also have an error handler interceptor. If for some reason, we loose connection to our Web Application, we have a popup component that informs the user about this. This popup component also has an image icon for displaying this error.

However, when we force the connection to be lost, the popup will show, but not have access to the image icon, since there is no connection.

So I'm looking for a way to include all these images when the application is being bundled together. Is there a way to preload the images from assets/img, when the application is being build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more than one way to do this. The first that comes to my mind is using a hidden image tag:

```
<img src="URL" style="display:none;" />.
```

Then it will be cached by the browser before it's *'used'*.

Another way would be to make a simple service that you run on your app components init.

```
function preloadImage(src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
}

ngOnInit() { 
    this.preloadImage('http://someurl/assests/imgs/img_001.jpg');
    // other onInit stuff
}
```

> So I'm looking for a way to include all these images when the application is being bundled together.

That's exactly what the assets folder is for.